# Syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Tags: php, mysql

Cuando intento correr mi pagina me arroja este error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Login18\Login\vista\admin.php on line 143

```
       <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>"> Buscar: 
      <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Buscar folio/estado" value="<?php echo $search ?>">
     <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
     </form>
     <br><br>
     <center>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tr>
   <th>Folio</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Rut</th>
      <th>Correo</th>
      <th>Telefono</th>
      <th>Direccion</th>
      <th>Poste</th>
      <th>Solicitud</th>
      <th>Fecha</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
      <th>Reporte</th>
      <th>Borrar</th>

    </tr>
    <?php
    foreach($model as $row)
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['nombre']."</td>";

    echo "<td>".$row['rut']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['phone']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['direccion']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['poste']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['mensaje']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['fecha']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['estado']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".
          if($row['estado'] == 'Resuelto'){
            echo '<span class="label label-success">Resuelto</span>';
          }
                        else if ($row['estado'] == 'Pendiente' ){
            echo '<span class="label label-info">Pendiente</span>';
          }
                        else if ($row['estado'] == 'Rechazado' ){
            echo '<span class="label label-warning">Rechazado</span>';
          }

          "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='actualizar.php?id=$row[0]' title='Editar datos' 
    class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit' aria-hidden='true'></span></td>";
    echo "<td><a href='eliminar.php?id=$row[0]&idborrar=2'' title='Eliminar'  class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' aria-hidden='true'></span></a><th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Concretamente, ¿Cuál es la linea que dispara el error?, añadela en la pregunta, diferenciándola del resto, por ejemplo, ponla abajo del todo, separada del otro código. También, estaría bien poner un contexto de cuál es la funcionalidad esperada del código y demás.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos errores, el primero es que en php no se escribe `else if`, sino `elseif`.

El segundo error es que no cierras la ejecución del `echo` que hay justo antes de la estructura `if`:

```
echo "<td>".

  if($row['estado'] == 'Resuelto'){
    echo '<span class="label label-success">Resuelto</span>';
  }
                else if ($row['estado'] == 'Pendiente' ){
    echo '<span class="label label-info">Pendiente</span>';
  }
                else if ($row['estado'] == 'Rechazado' ){
    echo '<span class="label label-warning">Rechazado</span>';
  }

  "</td>";
```

Intentas concatenar el `if` al `echo`, eso no se puede hacer. La solución sería:

```
 echo "<td>";
          if($row['estado'] == 'Resuelto'){
            echo '<span class="label label-success">Resuelto</span>';
          }
                        elseif ($row['estado'] == 'Pendiente' ){
            echo '<span class="label label-info">Pendiente</span>';
          }
                        elseif ($row['estado'] == 'Rechazado' ){
            echo '<span class="label label-warning">Rechazado</span>';
          }

 echo "</td>";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias , exacto esos eran los errores :)

Comment: @KacosPro En el ejemplo se me han colado, lo he copiado de la pregunta y no lo he cambiado :P, pero sí tengo una [referencia](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.elseif.php), `else if` se puede utilizar, pero no es lo recomendable. En cuanto a escribirlo mal en la respuesta, ahora mismo lo edito, fallo mío, gracias por darte cuenta, no caí :)

Answer (score 0):

Hay error en los **else if**, como explican aquí http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.elseif.php, debe escribirse junto **elseif**

Espero que sea de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Para mi que aquí te faltan ";"

```
echo "<td>".(algo) ;
```

y debes escribir **elseif** envés de **else if**